# Tag for font in .css theme file

Tags: css, themes, adobe-brackets

I am trying to custom a theme file for `Brackets`.
I like the font used in [Monokai](https://github.com/Brackets-Themes/Monokai) and the colours used in [Tomorrow Night](https://github.com/Brackets-Themes/TomorrowNight), so I would like to mix them.

The problem is that I can't find the `font` tag in `theme.css` of any of those two.

Where are those tags inside the files ? And what are they called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like themes you linked use default font "SourceCodePro-Medium". Homever, it's possible to change font-family in two ways:

1. You can change font-family of Brackets in `View > Themes` dialog.
2. In theme.css, add `font-family` tag to `body`. (Can be overridden by option 1)

> Don't set the editor font to a web font (@font-face) - this will cause
>   cursor positioning glitches.

Source: [Brackets Wiki](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Creating-Themes)

Comment: Thanks for that.
But by any ways, do you know what font & colours `Gedit` in `Ubuntu 14.04` uses? In preferences the it is `Classic`, which does not help